# Specific URL path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking for a method to catch these urls:

- https://my.server.com/subsite
- https://my.server.com/subsite.html

... but not these:

- https://my.server.com/otherpath/subsite
- https://my.server.com/other/path/subsite

---

What I got so far is this code - but obviously I'm also catching the urls I do not want to get (from above):

```
var express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get(/\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/, function(req, res) {

})
```

---

I tried to fix my code by inserting **com** before the regex but this does not seems to be a working solution: `/.*com\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/`.

> How can I get around this issue?

Comment: app.get('/subsite', function(req, res) {}) doesn't do what you want?  Not sure how you are initializing "app", so impossible to answer your question without seeing more code.

Comment: Edited some lines - This is all I got. @user2263572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
app.get(/.*com\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/, function(req, res) {

})
```

Here is where i tested it: https://regex101.com/r/42lhKg/1

Comment: might need to add / to the beginning and the end. not sure. regex101 does it for me.

Comment: like @user2263572 mentioned, it matter hows you initialized app. Also the intial regex from your question didnt work on regex101 for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a Reg Ex object, this will work fine:

```
app.get("/subsite(.html)?", function(req, res) {
    /*...*/
})
```

Matches any path beginning with "subsite" and with possibility of a .html

Comment: Yes. Looks pretty good but makes `my.server.com/xx/subsite.html` possible. I'd like to not catch this url for example (See my code above).

Comment: no it doesn't, first thing is that only the path would be parsed `/xx/subsite.html`.

If you wanted to also match that path you would need a star before /: `"*/subserver(.html)?"`

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is missing a the constraint to make subsite appear only in the begging `^`:

```
/^\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/
```

witch is the same as using just the string:

```
"/subsite(.html)?"
```

that I mentioned in the other answer.

Don't forget that in express you only care about the path and query part of the url.